# Makefile file function demo errors

Tags: linux, makefile

I was trying to get the result of file function in makefile for my demo with a small makefile as:

```
CMD = cat

OBJECTS = Makefile Makefile-filter-func

program : $(OBJECTS)
        $(file >$@.in) $(foreach O,$^,$(file >>$@.in,$O))
        @echo The file has been created.
all : 
        $(CMD) $(CMDFLAGS) @$@.in
        @echo The file contents are printed.
        @rm $@.in
        @echo The file removed.
```

I want to see the file the file name using ls command but this makefile has following error:

```
Makefile-file-func:7: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.
```

where am I getting wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer to the answer can be found in the source code of `make` (version 3.82), in the file [read.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/read.c):

```
989      /* This line starts with a tab but was not caught above because there
990         was no preceding target, and the line might have been usable as a
991         variable definition.  But now we know it is definitely lossage.  */
992      if (line[0] == cmd_prefix)
993        O (fatal, fstart, _("recipe commences before first target"));
```

With this information, it is possible to reproduce your issue by inserting spaces at the right spot. In the code below, `~` denotes a space and `<TAB>` denotes a `TAB`:

```
program : $(OBJECTS)
~~~~~~~~$(file >$@.in) $(foreach O,$^,$(file >>$@.in,$O))
 <TAB>  @echo The file has been created.
```

Since the spaces and tabs get lost in your question, it is a bit hard to see if this is exactly your case as well though.

Note that recipes are normally supposed to start with a `TAB`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ReinierTorenbeek  for reply. It solves my problem and helped me to understand the recipe from source code you provided the link.

Comment: Glad it helped, the tabs/spaces are always annoying with `make`.